# Как инициализировать Int переменную только цифрами из string переменной? Если буквы string переменной всегда известны?

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня есть String s она всегда равняется m+какое-то число.
И мне надо проинициализировать переменную int этим числом без m;
Пример:

```
String s = m28;
int i = 28;
String s1 = m29;
int i1 = 29;
```

Первая буква всегда m, а потом нужное мне число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "m28";
int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
System.out.println(i);
```

Этот способ быстрее, чем через `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

String являeтся неизменяемым, поэтому можно сделать следующим образом:

```
    String s = "m28";
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(s);
    s1.deleteCharAt(0);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s1));
    System.out.println(x);
```